# How to define a function based on a previously defined function on a module?

Tags: metaprogramming, elixir

I'm trying to define a function based on a already defined function on a module.

I want to do something like this:

```
defmodule A do
  def my_func(pid, arg1, arg2) do
    send pid, "Do Something"
  end
end
```

And after my_func is defined, I would like to define `my_func(arg1, arg2)` that calls `my_func` passing a pid that I'll get from a pool of pids for example.

My first attempt was using @on_definition but I had no success. Then I tried doing this inside the module:

```
Enum.each Module.definitions_in(__MODULE__, :def), fn {func_name, arity} ->
  args = Enum.map(0..arity-1, fn i -> "arg_#{i}" end)
      quoted = quote do
  def unquote(func_name)(unquote_splicing(args)) do
     ....
```

But still I'm not having success. Anyone have any idea on how do I get this? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this like so:

```
defmodule Test do
  def my_func(pid, arg1, arg2) do
    send pid, {arg1, arg2}
  end

  quoted = Enum.map Module.definitions_in(__MODULE__, :def), fn {func_name, _arity} ->
    quote do
      def unquote(func_name)(arg1, arg2) do
        pid = :some_pid
        unquote(func_name)(pid, arg1, arg2)
      end
    end
  end
  Module.eval_quoted(__MODULE__, quoted)

  Enum.each Module.definitions_in(__MODULE__, :def), fn {func_name, arity} ->
    IO.inspect {func_name, arity}
  end
end
```

If you compile this with `elixirc test.ex`, you'll see it spit out the definitions for `my_func/2` and `my_func/3`. The problem with your initial code was that while you were mapping over and quoting the definitions, you never evaluated those quoted expressions, so they were not compiled as part of your module.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the solution by bitwalker can be simplified. You don't need to quote and do `eval_quoted`, since `def` is a macro that injects directly into AST. So this will work as well:

```
defmodule Test do
  def my_func(pid, arg1, arg2) do
    send pid, {arg1, arg2}
  end

  Enum.map Module.definitions_in(__MODULE__, :def), fn {func_name, _arity} ->
    def unquote(func_name)(arg1, arg2) do
      pid = :some_pid
      unquote(func_name)(pid, arg1, arg2)
    end
  end

  Enum.each Module.definitions_in(__MODULE__, :def), fn {func_name, arity} ->
    IO.inspect {func_name, arity}
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice! Still a problem to me is how to define a function with the number of arguments that arity is. if arity = 3 -> def func_name(arg1, arg2, arg3) ...

Comment: Here's a gist that dynamically creates a n-arity function that returns a tuple consisting of all arguments: https://gist.github.com/sasa1977/ea3488e1c285ad527bc0

Comment: Nice! So, no easy way to do it using quote/unquote/Macro.methods?

Comment: Well, the example I've shown you uses unquote_splicing which means you can use it from macros, or when dynamically generating functions. I use this technique in ExActor to dynamically create interface functions, handler functions, and make a tuple message that is passed between processes.

Comment: I see. unquote_splicing was on my example too, I was talking about the "var creation magic": &{:"arg#{&1}", [], nil}
I was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. It appears it's possible using Code.string_to_quoted. I've updated the gist.

Comment: Maybe I should create a question for this and you answer again? You deserve some reputation :P

Comment: Hahaha, no need. My reward is that I've also learned something. Your question prompted me to look a bit deeper into docs, so I found out about Code.string_to_quoted :-)

Comment: @Eduardo it seems there is a recent addition in form of Macro.var/1 that makes the solution cleaner. I updated the gist again.